# Bootloader unlock HTC Desire 12+

Tags: htc, bootloader-lock

I am trying to unlock the bootloader of my HTC Desire 12+. I tried several tutorials but they all failed.

Here is what I did so far:

1. I boot the phone into recovery mode
2. Start the bootloader
3. After the phone started the bootloeader I try to find it with `fastboot devices` form my desktop computer (connected to the phone via USB)

   > PS C:\ADB> fastboot devices 5)
   >   d126ce6c        fastboot
4. I try to get the OEM identifier token

   > C:\ADB> fastboot oem get_identifier_token 
   >   FAILED (remote: unknown command) Finished. Total time: 0.000s

Here I am stuck.
I read online that for some HTC devices I need to enter the recovery/download mode. However, I do not even find my HTC device (via `fastboot devices`) in recovery mode nor do I know what the "download mode" is.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the wrong `fasstboot.exe` file. It worked when I choose the one provided in the section "All Other Supported Models" on https://www.htcdev.com/